# Fragment class fields gets nulled for unknown reason

Tags: java, android, oop, android-fragments

So I have a nested Fragment like:

```
public class AbstractFragment extends Fragment {
    public int resultCode;

    protected void startFragment(AbstractFragment fragment, int resultCode){
        this.resultCode = resultCode;
        Log.w(this, "startFragment(). fragment: "+fragment+" resultCode: "+this.resultCode);
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).addFragmentToBackStack(fragment);
    }
}
```

and the MainActivity has corresponding method:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    public void addFragmentToBackStack(Fragment fragment){
        Log.w(this, "addFragmentToBackStack(). fragment: "+fragment+" resultCode: "+((AbstractFragment) fragment).resultCode);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getName())
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
    }
}
```

and fragment is being started like

```
public class DynamicsFragment extends AbstractFragment{
public static final int DYNAMICS_CODE = 2;
...
startFragment(new DynamicsAddFragment(), DYNAMICS_CODE);
...
}
```

What I've got as a result is confusing me totally cuz fundamentals of OOP are not working here according to log:

```
03-05 21:35:05.700: W/DynamicsFragment(8533): startFragment(). fragment: DynamicsAddFragment{413453d8} requestCode: 2
03-05 21:35:05.700: W/MainActivity(8533): addFragmentToBackStack(). fragment: DynamicsAddFragment{413453d8} requestCode: 0
```

I checked the whole project expecting to find some code where I could potentially set `resultCode` to 0 but there is none. The only place `resultCode` is being set is in `startFragment` method of `AbstractFragment` and ofcourse `DynamicsAddFragment` extends `AbstractFragment`. Also `resultCode` would be set to zero if new instance of `DynamicsAddFragment` is created but there is no such code in the project.
Both log output lines goes one followed by one as it expected to execute. But ATM `startFragment` runs the resultCode field is initialized with 2 and at the same time when MainActivity method runs the field is empty already. The same happens with other fields like of String type for instance. But the instantiated fragment FOA is an OBJECT! And as you can see the object's runtime Id (unique runtime hash memory id {413453d8}) is the SAME! So its defenitely the same object! Its not the new/another instance of the same object! How could it be?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `this.resultCode = resultCode;` on `this`, i.e. on `DynamicsFragment`, while later you're getting this value from a different fragment, `DynamicsAddFragment`, I assume. This should work:

```
protected void startFragment(AbstractFragment fragment, int resultCode){
    fragment.resultCode = resultCode;
    Log.w(this, "startFragment(). fragment: "+fragment+" resultCode: "+fragment.resultCode);
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).addFragmentToBackStack(fragment);
}
```